# installed Qt5 but need Qt4 for MITK now

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, mitk

I have installed **Qt5** with Creator on my Windows machine. Now I need **Qt4.8** for **MITK** toolkit. What I should do? I have downloaded the qt-win-opensource-4.8.5-vs2010.exe. It says it is the **Qt libraries**. If I install it, will it mess up my development environment?

Is there any zipped version I can just unzip it into a location and set MITK CMake to that location?

Answer (score 1):

After install Qt 4.8.5 you can add Qt4 libraries to Qt Creator. In Qt Creator click `Tools -> Options -> Buil&Run` and then select `Qt Versions` tab and add Qt4 libraries. After that select `Kits` tab and add new Qt4 kit.